# Godaddy - Connecting Mysql with GUI Mysql-Front Tool

Tags: mysql

How to connect godaddy mysql server database with my locally installed mysql front tool (GUI Tool for managing remote databases)?

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : First Find your IP address 
Step2 : Login to your godaddy dashboard and search for 'Remote MySQL' click on the icon/link 
Step3 : Enter your ip into 'Add Access Host' Field and click Add Host.

Now enter your godaddy detail into mysql front and go e.g  
 - host name (www.example.com),  
 - db name, 
 - db username,  
 - db password